# Nuxt.js - accessing store state in axios plugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I have a token in the store, but I can't access it in my axios plugin. I used to simply import the store when using just Vue, really struggling to understand how to do this in Nuxt.js

I need to access a token value from my store, and use it in the 'Authorization' attribute below.

#### Here's my current code;

```js
// /plugins/axios.js
import axios from 'axios'
import { state } from '../store'

export default () => {
    const api = axios.create({
        baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer` + xxxx ACCESS STORE STATE HERE xxxx,
        },
    })

    return api
}
```

```js
// nuxt.config.js
...
{
  plugins: ['~/plugins/persistedState.client.js', '~/plugins/axios'],
}
...
```

```js
// store/index.js
export const state = () => ({
    token: null,
    user: null,
    isUserLoggedIn: false,
})
```

As state is returned as a function from my store/index.js, I can't get this to work and clearly isn't the solution!

### What I've tried

Looking at docs and at old posts on this it looks like I need to pass { store } as an argument but I get the error `Cannot destructure property 'store' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.`

For example...

```js
export default ({ store }) => {
    const api = axios.create({
        baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer` + store.state.token,
        },
    })

    return api
}
```

I've also tried setting the Authorization header in the store itself as an alternative, but this doesn't have any effect when posting to my server, no authorization header is supplied.

```js
// store/index.js
...
export const mutations = {
    setToken(state, token) {
        state.token = token
        state.isUserLoggedIn = !!token
        this.$axios.setHeader('Authorization', '123')
    },
```

At a bit of loss with this and any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please tell your `nuxt` and `axios` versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plugin functions should be pure and should not re-assign the value of `$this` by using a `=>` (fat arrow).

You can tap into the current `$axios` instance and set the header whenever a request is made:

```
// plugins/axios.js
export default function ({ $axios, store }) {
  $axios.onRequest(config => {
    const { token } = store.state

    if (token) {
      config.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
    }

  })
}
```

Mind you that `$axios` is a package provided by `@nuxtjs/axios` and `this.$axios` will differ from `this.axios` if you've manually registered `axios` by its self.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. Using the code above I get the error `Cannot destructure property '$axios' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.` Any ideas?

Comment: Resolved - It was because was still importing the axios.js file above into another module.